# ComBSTR assignment

Tags: com, com-interop, atl, bstr

I'm confused about COM string assignments. Which of the following string assignment is correct. Why?

```
CComBSTR str;
.
.
Obj->str = L""  //Option1
```

OR should it be

```
Obj->str = CComBSTR(L"")  //Option2
```

What is the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `str = CComBSTR(L"")` you use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0dsx8by.aspx):

```
CComBSTR( LPCSTR pSrc );
```

If you use `str = L""` you use the [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h2b71be.aspx):

```
CComBSTR& operator =(LPCSTR pSrc);
```

They both would initialize the CComBSTR object correctly.

Answer (score 4):

A real `BSTR` is:

- temporarily allocated from the COM heap (via `SysAllocString()` and family)
- a data structure in which the string data is preceded by its length, stored in a 32-bit value.
- passed as a pointer to the fifth byte of that data structure, where the string data resides.

See the documentation:
[MSDN: BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx)

Most functions which accept a `BSTR` will not crash when passed a BSTR created  the simple assignment.  This leads to confusion as people observe what seems to be working code from which they infer that a `BSTR` can be initialized just like any `WCHAR *`.  That inference is incorrect.

Only real `BSTRs` can be passed to OLE Automation interfaces.

By using the `CComBSTR()` constructor, which calls `SysAllocString()`, your code will create a real `BSTR`.  The `CComBSTR()` destructor will take care of returning the allocated storage to the system via `SysFreeString()`.

If you pass the `CComBSTR()` to an API which takes ownership, be sure to call the `.Detach()` method to ensure the `BSTR` is not freed.  `BSTRs` are ***not*** reference counted (unlike COM objects, which are), and therefore an attempt to free a `BSTR` more than once will crash.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd prefer option 1, because that doesn't require constructing a new `CComBSTR` object. (Whether their code does so behind the scenes is a different story, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is preferred because it only does one allocation for the string where as option 2 does 2 (not withstanding the creation of a new temporary object for no particular reason). Unlike the bstr_t type in VC++ the ATL one does not do referenced counted strings so it will copy the entire string across.